# pagify.js and reloading / refreshing div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Newbie here, so please forgive me if this is a simple question:

I've got a single-page website using pafigy to hash the urls.  When the page is first loaded, it pulls in the "home.html" file into the content div.

The "home.html" content contains scripts (jquery cycle) that need to run when it is loaded into the "content" div of the index page.  If I link to the cycle plugin and jquery libraries in the "home.html" page, it loads into the "content" div VERY slowly.  So, I load the libraries on the main page and reference them in the "home.html" page.

It works fine when the site is initially loaded; however, if I click another menu item and then try to return to "#home" (either with the back button or with a link to "#home"), it loads the content from "home.html", but doesn't load the cycle plugin.

So, I know I need to refresh/reload the javascript in the "content" div, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.  Any help or words of wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the pagify script on the index.html page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').pagify({
        pages: ['home', 'food', 'wine'],
        animation: 'fadeIn',
        'default': 'home',
        cache: true

    });
});
</script>
```

And here is the Jquery Cycle script on the home.html page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#myslides').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speedIn: 1000,
        speedOut: 200,
        delay: 1200,
        cleartypeNoBg: true
    });

    $('#myslides2').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollLeft',
        speedIn: 700,
        speedOut: 500,
        delay: 1000,
        cleartypeNoBg: true
    });
});​
</script>
```

Again, forgive me if my code is wonky or if I'm doing this completely wrong.  I'm trying to learn as best I can and research, but I'm really stuck here.

Also, let me know if you need more code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to fire Cycle after you load that page. Perhaps you can achieve that with the onChange option present on pagify.js. It should look something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content').pagify({
        pages: ['home', 'food', 'wine'],
        animation: 'fadeIn',
        'default': 'home',
        cache: true,
        'onChange': function(home) { //wrap 'onChange' in quotes
           $('#myslides').cycle({
           //Your Cycle Plugin Goes Here
           });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this idea helps.